# Add class to parent based on image src attribute

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm having a problem where a CMS is spitting out a grid of images based on a template, but if the project has less images than the grid it will spit out the blanks as well. So I want to add a class of to the parent element to hide the blanks based on the blank image src attribute. Here is what I have:

HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="#">
     <img src="image-1.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item"> <!-- Need to add class of 'hide' -->
  <a href="#">
     <img src=""> <!-- Blank Img -->
  </a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var image = $("div.item > a > img");
var srcs = image.attr('src');

$.each(image, function () {
   if(srcs.length == 0){
      $(this).closest('div').addClass("hide");
   }
});
```

Since I am a bit of a noob at this it's probably something simple. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
$('img[src=""]').parents ('div.item').hide()
```

Description: 
Selector find all img elements with empty source and parents method return paretns with given selector and finaly hide with actuallu hides div.item selector.

regarding to what @Felix suggests this is more efficeint:

```
$('img[src=""]').closest ('div.item').hide()
```

Comment: `.closest` is better than `.parents` in this case.

Comment: I dont think so. I filtered div with item class, so that's not to be an issue. But surely closest will work perfectly. leave it up to @Archetype and context

Comment: Well, `.parents` will unnecessarily traverse up the DOM even after it finds the first `div.item` element. Avoiding unnecessary computation is better, isn't it? And since the OP is already using it, I would just keep it.

Comment: Excellent help here @Boynux & @FelixKling! Thanks so much. I had not thought to use the .hide() or .remove() but that is so much cleaner. I ultimately arrived at using this along with using the .each() function that John suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

`image.attr('src')` will always return the `src` attribute value of **the first selected element**.

You want to test the attribute value of each element. You can use [`.filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do this easily:

```
$('div.item > a > img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src').length === 0;
}).closest('div.item').addClass('hide');
```

Or use the [attribute equals selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('div.item > a > img[src=""]').closest('div.item').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr("src")` will return the `src` attribute.

I would use `each` jQuery function for `img`.

```
$("img").each(function () {
    if($(this).attr("src") == "") {
         $(this).closest('div').addClass("hide").text("Hide class was added.");
    }
});
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rAKmE/1/).

You can see the screen shoot bellow.

I used the following CSS style for `.hide`:

```
.hide {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks John! I used this and ended up going away from the addClass and just using .remove to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your version of the code, so you can learn from it. You also will learn how to use the $.each().

```
 var image = $("div.item > a > img");

 $.each(image, function (idx, element) {
   if($(element).attr('src').length == 0){
      $(this).closest('div').addClass("hide");
       // remove
       $(this).closest('div').hide();
   }
});
```

You can play with it on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r84NR/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/adoveb/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('img[src=""]').closest('.item').hide();
```

additionally instead of `.hide()` you can use `.remove()`